# End-to-End tests for Office Add-in using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have not been able to find guidelines about how to run e2e automation tests using Cypress for Add-in in Word online. Using Angular NX for development (https://nx.dev/latest/angular/tutorial/02-add-e2e-test).

Can we run tests using Cypress for ADD-IN in office online versions?
Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you want to test it this way? Is that add-in running in the browser?

Comment: Yes, Add-in is running in browser and want to do automation test using cypress

Comment: Then this should be working. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I hope this can be helpful to you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-browser-extension-plugin